# Rewrite rule catch all + QSA not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to show a default view (home) when the user lands in the root of my site, this is what I use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ index.php?view=home [L]
```

With this other rule, I'm trying to catch everything that has variables (since all my paths are rewritten, I should never have something like mydomain.com?somevar=true, so i look for & or = or ?), and pass the query string to a page

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^([\&|\=|\?]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ badstuff.php [L,QSA]
```

What I don't understand is that mydomain.com/?test=true is redirected to index.php?view=home instead of going to badstuff.php

What am i doing wrong? If I comment the 1st cond + rule, the second rule is never matched...

Thanks you.

**Edit:** Added more rules for better understanding. Forgot to mention, **Apache 2.4**
This is what I have now

```
#standard views
Rewriterule ^home$ index.php?view=home [L] (works)
Rewriterule ^about$ index.php?view=about [L] (works)

#default view
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ index.php?view=home [L] (works)

#bad stuff
Rewriterule ^[\?=&]$ badstuff.php [L,QSA] (doesnt work)
```

Comment: This `^([\&|\=|\?]+)$` says you can have any number of `&=?` (at least one) it doesn't allow for anything else such as alpha characters. You also don't need to escape in a character class except... `In most regex flavors, the only special characters or metacharacters inside a character class are the closing bracket (]), the backslash (\), the caret (^), and the hyphen (-).` -http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: @chris85 How to write "if you find & or if you find = or if you find ? in between other stuff " ? Also why  mydomain.com/?test=true redirects to index.php?view=home when my request_uri ins't just / ?

Comment: This `[&?].+?=.+` would be `&` or `?` then anything until the first `=` and then anything. Take a look at http://regex101.com and you can test out regexs there. Here's a demo, https://regex101.com/r/yJ1xO6/1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your chief issue here is that you are attempting to match a query string inside `REQUEST_URI`, but that variable does not contain the query string.

[From the Apache docs:](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

> REQUEST_URI
>   The path component of the requested URI, such as "/index.html". This notably excludes the query string which is available as its own variable named QUERY_STRING.

So instead, you just need to match any non-empty character inside `%{QUERY_STRING}`, and you must place that rule before the rule matching `/` because `/?abc=123` would still match the `/` rule.

```
# Match a non-empty query string (. is any one character)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
# Don't apply this if the view= has already been applied
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !view=
# Rewrite to badstuff.php and append the params.
RewriteRule ^.*$ badstuff.php [L,QSA]

# Then rewrite the root
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ index.php?view=home [L]
```

#### Better version:

I would simplify your first rule a bit to eliminate the `RewriteCond` since only the path needs to be matched by `RewriteRule`. I've also removed all the `()` capture groups because you are not actually using the values they capture.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !view=
# Rewrite to badstuff.php and append the params.
RewriteRule .* badstuff.php [L,QSA]

# Match a non-empty path into view=
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?view=$1 [L]
# Then a simpler rule that matches ^$ (no path)
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?view=home [L]
```

If you applied this in a VirtualHost config instead of .htaccess, the `RewriteRule` would include the leading `/`, so you'd need to use instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ index.php?view=home [L]
```

But `/` is *not* used in .htaccess.

Now, if the `!view=` is too broadly preventing the query string from matching, you may resort to matching in `THE_REQUEST` for query params.

```
# Match any query string in the raw request
RewriteCond THE_REQUEST \?[^=]+
RewriteRule .* badstuff.php [L,QSA]

#... Then the other rules
```

Comment: @Eric Okay, when the view= is rewritten, the query string is then matched. I added a negative check for `view=` there, but that may not be sufficient.  Also, since you added more stuff, I created a matching rule for `/about, /home` etc.